# How can I make a login for multiple users in Symfony2

Tags: symfony

I am trying to make a login for two types of users  'User' 'and Teacher' in symfony, but I still keep getting this errors: `Unable to find the controller for path "/user/login_check". Maybe you forgot to add the matching route in your routing configuration?`

Here is the Security.yml

> security:
>       encoders:
>           AUI\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\Teacher:
>               algorithm:        md5
>               encode_as_base64: true
>               iterations:       1

```
    AUI\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\Student:
        algorithm:        md5
        encode_as_base64: true
        iterations:       1

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_TEACHER:       ROLE_STUDENT
    ROLE_SUPER_TEACHER: ROLE_TEACHER
    ROLE_ADMIN: [ ROLE_SUPER_TEACHER, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH ]

providers:   
    #property: the field you want to use in the login, email or username=> email was chosen here

    admin_area:
        name: admin_security
        entity: { class: AUIUserBundle:Teacher, property: email }
    student_area:
        name: student_security
        entity: { class: AUIUserBundle:Student, property: username }

firewalls:
    admin_area:
        pattern: ^/
        anonymous: ~
        provider: admin_security
        form_login:
            login_path: login
            check_path: login_check
            default_target_path: /admin/admin_panel

        logout:
            path:   /admin_logout
            target: /login

    student_area:
        pattern: ^/user
        provider: student_security
        form_login:
            login_path: /user/login
            check_path: student_login_check
            default_target_path: /index


        logout:
            path:   /student_logout
            target: /student_login
```

and here is the routing.yml

```
login:
    pattern: login
    defaults: { _controller:AUIUserBundle:Security:Login}

login_check:
    path: login_check

logout:
    path: /admin_logout


student_login:
    pattern: /user/login
    defaults: { _controller:AUIUserBundle:Security:StudentLogin}

student_login_check:
    path: /user/login_check

student_logout:
    path: /student/logout
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed the controller/action section into your `routing.yml`

It should be something like:

```
student_login_check:
    path: /user/login_check
    defaults: { _controller: AUIUserBundle:Security:StudentLoginCheck }
```

Of course `AUIUserBundle:Security:StudentLoginCheck` is just an example

Comment: No, normally logincheck is implemented automatically in symphony. you don't implement the action yourself (it is already implemented for you). the login is working for the admin without that action(login_check) that you have just specified. but its not working for the user for other reasons

Comment: @anyavacy /login_check is one thing but /user/login_check is totally differenti one. Try to make a simple controller for simulate thst and modify tour routing file ad I told you...

Comment: so for another login check, I need to implement it. The framework cannot support both of them or what? from my understanding the login_check(any login check) is implemented by default in the framework, you just need to configure the security.yml file. am I wrong?

Comment: @anyavacy: you're not wrong, infact you can use the same controller to perform authentication action. BUT (yes, there's a BUT) you have to specify it into your routing file. So if you want to use the same controller you have to understand properly which - if any - controller is called upon authentication (I'm pretty sure there isn't as should be a service) or simulate a call to some service you have to implement/tag properly... Now I can't dig better into Symfony2 architecture otherwise I would have done and told you exactly. However you have to follow mine answer to make things works properly

Comment: what I have done actually is let one controller handle the login automatically for one user, and I have programmed the other login manually without the interaction of the framework. I followed your approach somewho :). thanks by the ways, you get some votes up

Answer (score 0):

The way I have solved this issue is by leaving the framework handle the login for one type of users, and I then programmed the other login manually, which means that I have coded the 'logincheckAction'. Could not find any better way to do that. All the other ways failed for me